# What is the equivalent of php array() in objective-c

Tags: php, objective-c, arrays, xcode, multidimensional-array

How can I do this:

PHP:

```
$arr1 = array( 'a', 1, 'b', 5, 'z' );
$arr2 = array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' );
$arr3 = array( 'key1' => 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' );
```

and this:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

In Objective-C ?

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an array

```
  NSMutableArray *arr1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"a", @"b", nil];
    for (NSString *obj in arr1) {
        // do stuff
    }
```

And for a map

```
  NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:keys forKeys:values];
    for (id key in dict) {
        id value = [dict valueForKey:key];
        // do stuff with value
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

$arr1 --- > [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) Or [NSMutabelArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

$arr2 --- > [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSMutabelDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**See accessing values from  NSDirectiory.**

```
NSDirectiory* arr2;
for (NSString* myKey in arr2)
{
    id value = [arr2 objectForKey:myKey];
}
```

**See accessing values from  NSMutableArray.**

```
NSMutableArray * arr1;
for (id* object in arr1) {
  //id hold the value of your object stored in array.
}
```

Comment: and $arr3 and the foreach(...){...} ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143372/for-each-loop-in-objective-c-for-accessing-nsmutable-dictionary/2143389#2143389