# Cant access serialized JSON data (NSJSONSerialization)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get this JSON from a web service:

```
{
    "Respons": [{
        "status": "101",
        "uid": "0"
    }]
}
```

I have tried to access the data with the following:

```
NSError* error;

//Response is a NSArray declared in header file.
self.response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString *test = [[self.response objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"status"]; //[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
NSString *test = [[self.response objectForKey:@"status"] objectAtIndex:0]; //(null)
```

But none of them work, if i NSLog the NSArray holding the serialized data, this i what i get:

```
{
Respons = (
    {
        status = 105;
        uid = 0;
    }
);
}
```

How do i access the data?

Comment: Read the error. The JOSN is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: self.response should be an NSDictionary

Comment: See json.org.  Learn how to read the JSON (it takes about 10 minutes to learn).  Then understand how decoded JSON dumps with NSLog (almost like the original JSON, only `()` is used instead of `[]` for an array and not everything is quoted).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing JSON data inside an NSDictionary generated from NSJSONSerialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588264/accessing-json-data-inside-an-nsdictionary-generated-from-nsjsonserialization)

Comment: @HotLicks Im perfectly capable of reading and writing JSON, have been using it for years in web development.

Comment: Then how come you can't figure out how to access the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON represents a dictionary, for whom the value associated with the `Respons` key is an array. And that array has a single object, itself a dictionary. And that dictionary has two keys, `status` and `uid`.

So, for example, if you wanted to extract the status, I believe you need:

```
NSArray *array = [self.response objectForKey:@"Respons"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *status = [dictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Or, in latest versions of the compiler:

```
NSArray *array = self.response[@"Respons"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = array[0];
NSString *status = dictionary[@"status"];
```

Or, more concisely:

```
NSString *status = self.response[@"Respons"][0][@"status"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, when i try to compare `status` with a string i get the following warning: Comparison of distinct pointer types 'NSString *' 'char *'

Code: NSDictionary *test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    
    NSArray *array = test[@"Respons"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = array[0];
    NSString *status = dictionary[@"status"];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", status);
    
    if (status == "100") {
        //
    } else {
        //
    }

Comment: @user1359448 Two problems: 1. You don't compare strings with `==` operator; you use `isEqualToString`. 2. You forgot the `@` in `@"100"`. Thus, it should be `if ([status isEqualToString:@"100"]) ...`. Either that or `if ([status integerValue] == 100) ...`, which converts the string to a number (avoiding hassles if there was a space in there or something weird like that).

Answer (score 1):

Your top level object isn't an array, it's a dictionary. You can easily bypass this and add the contents of that key to your array.

```
self.response = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error] objectForKey:@"Respons"];
```