# Getting values from NSDictionary in foreach?

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I have a view that has tableviewcells on it, loaded with different "key values" as the label.  When I tap on one I open another view.  However here, I pass the dictionary for just that key, for example I would pass this:

```
{
    key = Budget;
    value =     {
        "2012 Budget Report" =         {
            active = 0;
            author = "xxxxx xxxxxx";
            date = "October 27, 2012";
            description = "Example";
            dl = "53 downloads";
            email = "xxx@xxxxx.com";
            ext = DOCX;
            fortest = "Tuesday, November 6";
            id = 5;
            subject = budget;
            testdate = "Tuesday, November 6";
            title = "Budget spreadSheet";
        };
        "2005 - 2008 Budget Report" =         {
            active = 0;
            author = "xxxxxxx xxxxx";
            date = "November 3, 2012";
            description = "Example";
            dl = "18 downloads";
            email = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com";
            ext = DOCX;
            title = "Budget report";
        };
    };
}
```

How do I get each of these values?  Thanks.

Please note:  the titles in value array are subject to change... More could be added, one could be deleted, so I need a general solution.

Comment: Is array = [dictionary valueForKey:Budget]; possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering the dictionary you passed is saved in `iDictionary`.

```
NSDictionary *iDictionary // Input Dictionary;
NSDictionary *theValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[iDictionary valueForKey:@"value"]];

for (NSString *aKey in [theValues allKeys]) {
    NSDictionary *aValue = [theValues valueForKey:aKey];
    NSLog(@"Key : %@", aKey);
    NSLog(@"Value : %@", aValue);

    // Extract individual values
    NSLog(@"Author : %@", [aValue objectForKey:@"author"]);

    // If the titles are dynamic
    for (NSString *aSubKey in [aValue allKeys]) {
        NSString *aSubValue = [aValue objectForKey:aSubKey];

        NSLog(@"SubKey : %@, SubValue = %@", aSubKey, aSubValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: should also check the answer on this page for an easy to understand implementation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143372/for-each-loop-in-objective-c-for-accessing-nsmutable-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *arrBudget= [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Budget"];
```

So here `arrBudget` will contain All the values And you can Pass the array to detail view.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if keys and objects are useful in the "foreach" logic :

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"key1": @"value1",
    @"key2": @"value2",
    @"key3": @"value3",
};  
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Your key : %@", key);
    NSLog(@"Your value : %@", [obj description]);
    // do something...
}];
```