# How to get key and value from an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

This is my code but it does not log any keys or values

```
NSDictionary *d = @{
      @"foo": @"bar",
      @"abc": @"def"
    };

    for (NSString* key in d.allKeys) {
        NSString *value = (NSString *)[d objectForKey:key];
        NSLog(@"areacodedisplay: value = %@",value);
        NSLog(@"areacodedisplay: key = %@",key);
    }
```

How to get key and value from an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Please explain the question because the code works and produces: `areacodedisplay: value = bar` and `areacodedisplay: key = foo`.

Comment: Yep there is nothing wrong with this code works fine for me.

Comment: Of course, there's no need to use `.allKeys`.

Comment: You may need to set Xcode to show the log window. Shift-command-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look here: [for each loop in objective c for accessing NSMutable dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143372/for-each-loop-in-objective-c-for-accessing-nsmutable-dictionary)

```
for (NSString* key in d) {
    id value = [d objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"areacodedisplay: value = %@",value);
    NSLog(@"areacodedisplay: key = %@",key);
}
```

Comment: @totalitarian - Uh, maybe it's those things called "key" and "value".

Comment: This is essentially identical to the OP's code. Iterating an `NSDictionary` (as in this answer) is the same as iterating the keys (as in the OP's code). So I'm confused as to why this answer was accepted. If this works then the OP's code must also work.

Comment: @rmaddy - The whole question deserves to be closed as "can no longer be reproduced".

Answer (score 2):

This code works:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{
    @"foo": @"bar"
};
    
for (NSString* key in d.allKeys)
{
    NSString *value = [d objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@" value = %@",value);
    NSLog(@"key = %@",key);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i've fixed my code, the NSDictionary should have 2 objects. Only the frist key>value get printed out

Answer (score -1):

var Dict1 = NSMutuabledictionary()
dict1.setValue(lbl1.text ?? "", forKey: "name")
dict1.setValue(lbl2.text ?? "", forKey: "email")
dict1.setValue( lbl3.text ?? "", forKey: "phone")
dict1.setValue( lbl4.text ?? "", forKey: "date")
dict1.setValue(lbl15.text ?? "", forKey: "password")
dict1.setValue( lbl6.text ?? "", forKey: "confirm")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.